# Best way to create a menu dynamically from database

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

im tryng to create a menu from the database dynamically.

Suppose i have the table:

```
MENU (
  ID,
  NAME,
  URL,
  FATHER
)
```

And the data

[Data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmKxM.png)

Now i want to map the info using hibernate in the class

```
public class Menu {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String url;
    private List<Menu> childMenu;
}
```

So i can create a JSON from that class that looks something like

```
"menu": 
               [
                  {"name": "Menu1", "url": "www.google.com", "childMenu": null},
                  {"name": "Menu2", "url": "1", "childMenu": 
                     [
                        {"name": "childMenu1","url": "www.google.com", "childMenu": null},
                        {"name": "childMenu2","url": "www.google.com", "childMenu": null},
                        {"name": "childMenu3","url": "www.google.com", "childMenu": null}
                     ]
                  },
                  {"name": "Menu3", "url": "www.google.com", "childMenu": 
                     [
                        {"name": "childMenu1","url": "www.google.com", "childMenu": null},
                        {"name": "childMenu2","url": "www.google.com", "childMenu": null}
                     ]
                   }   
               ]
```

Any idea on how to do it with hibernate, so i dont have to use nested for?

Thank you.

Comment: There's not really much information here to go on. If you're using Spring and Jackson, it should be pretty simple to achieve what you want here...

Comment: i'm using spring and jackson, but the main question is how to map the table to the class so the class will have all of its children menu.
I don't want to iterate over every single menú finding its children

Comment: If child menu is always linked to just 1 level above (so no cross links between menus), then you can just keep the master id in every record and a child level & second master id to indicate how deep it is nested. Then you can retrieve it in 1 go without nested queries.

Comment: any example on how to do that @NorbertvanNobelen

Answer (score 0):

Roughly:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MENU")
public class Menu {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "URL")
    private String url;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "FATHER", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private List<Menu> childMenu;
}
```

You shouldn't require any special `@Json*` annotations here just because you are not mapping both ends of the `FATHER` relationship here. If you are, you will need to add a `@JsonIgnore` to the `father` field as well.

Answer (score 0):

Alter the table so it has 1 extra column:

```
MENU (
  MASTER_ID,
  ID,
  NAME,
  URL,
  FATHER
);
```

`MASTER_ID` contains the main menu item ID: Example:

```
MASTER_ID | ID | NAME      | URL      | FATHER
NULL      | 1  | some_menu | some_url | NULL
```

Is a main menu item.

A child item:

```
MASTER_ID | ID | NAME       | URL       | FATHER
1         | 2  | some_menu2 | some_url2 | 1
```

A child child:

```
MASTER_ID | ID | NAME       | URL       | FATHER
1         | 3  | some_menu2 | some_url2 | 2
```

As you notice: The `MASTER_ID` can be used to retrieve a complete menu tree in just 1 query without having to join the table back on itself.